# How to add rows in pandas until condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this:

```
x     y    frames
0    10     7 
1    14     8    
1    19     9
3    11     10
```

I want to add rows to the top of the dataframe so that `frames` can start at 0 and increment up by 1 until it reaches the first original `frames` value. I want to add NaN values for all other columns.

I tried this, but it takes forever and eventually crashes:

```
starting_frame = int(df.frames.values[0])
print(starting_frame)
count = 0
while count < starting_frame:
    row = ['', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
       np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
       '', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,
       count]
    d = pd.DataFrame(row)
    df = pd.concat([d, df])
    count+=1

print(df)
```

It should look like this:

```
x     y    frames
NaN   NaN     0 
NaN   NaN     1 
NaN   NaN     2 
NaN   NaN     3 
NaN   NaN     4 
NaN   NaN     5 
NaN   NaN     6 
0      10     7 
1      14     8    
1      19     9
3      11     10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `reindex`

```
out = df.set_index('frames').reindex(range(df['frames'].max()+1)).reset_index()

out
Out[545]: 
    frames    x     y
0        0  NaN   NaN
1        1  NaN   NaN
2        2  NaN   NaN
3        3  NaN   NaN
4        4  NaN   NaN
5        5  NaN   NaN
6        6  NaN   NaN
7        7  0.0  10.0
8        8  1.0  14.0
9        9  1.0  19.0
10      10  3.0  11.0
```

Comment: This works for getting the right values in frames, but it turns all of the x and y values in NaN

Comment: @connor449 check your column type , it works fine on my side

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Series for the missing values of frames and use concat to preprend it to you DataFrame

```
In [66]: pd.concat([pd.Series(range(0, df.loc[0, 'frames']), name='frames').to_frame(), df]).reset_index(drop=True)                                                                                        
Out[66]: 
    frames    x     y
0        0  NaN   NaN
1        1  NaN   NaN
2        2  NaN   NaN
3        3  NaN   NaN
4        4  NaN   NaN
5        5  NaN   NaN
6        6  NaN   NaN
7        7  0.0  10.0
8        8  1.0  14.0
9        9  1.0  19.0
10      10  3.0  11.0
```

Comment: This works for getting the right values in `frames`, but it turns all of the `x` and `y` values in NaN

Answer (score 0):

Problems in your code:

1. Using `pd.DataFrame(row)`, you are creating a series rather than a row in dataframe.
2. Using `pd.concat([d, df])` and `count += 1`, the bigger frames will be on top.

To fix these, you could use

```py
starting_frame = int(df.frames.values[0])

count = starting_frame - 1

while count >= 0:
    row = [np.nan, np.nan, count]

    d = pd.DataFrame([row], columns=['x', 'y', 'frames'])

    df = pd.concat([d, df])
    count -= 1

print(df)
```

You can also create a helper dataframe whose `frames` column value starts from 0, and merge `df` on that helper dataframe.

```py
df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame({'frames': range(df['frames'].max() + 1)}), how='right')
```

```py
# print(df)

      x     y  frames
0   NaN   NaN       0
1   NaN   NaN       1
2   NaN   NaN       2
3   NaN   NaN       3
4   NaN   NaN       4
5   NaN   NaN       5
6   NaN   NaN       6
7   0.0  10.0       7
8   1.0  14.0       8
9   1.0  19.0       9
10  3.0  11.0      10
```